# Options menu created for android app causes app to crash

Tags: java, android

I have been in the process of developing a mobile game using android studio. I am trying to create an options menu off of the main menu screen but anytime the app is ran and the options menu is accessed, the app crashes before loading the options menu. I have laboured over the code I have written and attempted to find what the problem is however I am unable to discover why the code is crashing.

If needed I can provide the java class I have been working with. It would be a great help if anyone could tell me what or why the code may be crashing.

Comment: In order for us to tell you what the problem is, we have to take a look at your code. Please upload them.

Comment: also, it would help even better if you could add your logcat with the errors you're getting when your app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Need more context, code or log would be helpful.

You will need to override these 2 methods in your Activity. first is to create menu, the second one is to handle the option select.

```
@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {} 
@Override  
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {}
```

Check: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu